# MATCH with multiple criterias always returns #NA even there is data

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

Ive a scenario to find match index of two values in two columns. So based on this link [Click](https://spreadsheeto.com/index-match/) I tried this way for the following data.

```
Holidays    Location    Multiplier
26-01-2018  INDIA   2
01-05-2018  INDIA   2
15-06-2018  INDIA   2
15-08-2018  INDIA   2
02-10-2018  INDIA   2
19-10-2018  INDIA   2
06-11-2018  INDIA   2
25-12-2018  INDIA   2
26-01-2018  SINGAPORE   2
```

---

Here is my formula on `G2`

```
=MATCH(1,(B2:B10="INDIA"),0)
```

But it returns #NA always

But if I try

```
=MATCH("INDIA",B2:B10,0)
```

It returns `1` which is correct. So whats wrong with the other way

Comment: Are you finalizing the former with ctrl+shift+enter instead of just enter?

Comment: Just enter to submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True is the same as 1 only when used in a maths operation; not in direct comparison. Try it as,

```
=MATCH(TRUE,(B2:B10="INDIA"),0)
```

Remember to finalize with ctrl+shift+enter instead of just enter.

Comment: Hey man.. you are a life saver.. I missed ctrl+shift+enter... That works now.. Cheers mate..

Answer (score 2):

If you open "Formula Evaluate" Box and see what is happening with formula

`=MATCH(1,(B2:B10="INDIA"),0)`

then you will find that normal entry is causing it to evaluate for single cell only i.e. `B2`.

And the result of check is `TRUE`. So when Excel tries to match it with numeric result it correctly returns `#N/A' as it cannot find 1.

So first you need to enter it as array formula (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) like:

`=MATCH(1,(B2:B10="INDIA")+0,0)`

which causes results to be numeric or you can use:

`=MATCH(TRUE,(B2:B10="INDIA"),0)`